# In BIRT report label display on the last page

Tags: eclipse, birt

I have a BIRT report that I need to add a line to the bottom of the last page.  But that adds the line right after the data. I need the line to be at the bottom of the last page only.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please add the code you have so far for a better understanding of your problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without patching BIRT.